# Run Selenium RC script on any browser that is available on user's system

Tags: browser, system, selenium-rc

I have a selenium script which i want to run on some other user's machine. I have set 'firefox' as my default browser in the selenium script. 
Now the user's machine does not have 'firefox' installed on his machine.
Is there any code available that can fetch which browser is installed on that user's machine and run the script in that browser?

I want to have 3 browsers in my script like IE, Firefox and Chrome.
The script must run on any one browser which is installed on user's machine.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would either have to have some code that looks for each kind of browser (e.g. looking for the executable such as chrome.exe or firefox.exe) or you might be able to get away with some try-catch blocks that try to get Selenium to launch the browser, and treat any exceptions as 'browser didn't exist'.

I would suggest that specifically checking for each browser type is the better option though.

You could then build up a list of the available browsers and have some code to select one of them (based on some kind of priority/preference) as the target for Selenium

Comment: That sounds a lot like Selenium Grid without a browser-type DesiredCapability.